# How do I retrieve my delimiters as well as string tokens into a single array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created two arrays;
~one contains my delimiters
~the other contains my numbers

now I want to get them all into a single array(finalVector[ ])!!
Reason:
I need to pass above mentioned "finalVector" to a method which checks whether there is a multiplication sign(*) in the array and if so applies brackets accordingly.
If I don't tokenize my array then it will return:
34*2 as 3(4*2) taking 4 as a single value. Since I want it to take 34 itself as a single value and return (34*2) I tokenized the array and retrieved the numbers into array newVector02[].
But I can't pass newVector02[] to the method since it will only pass the numbers and the method will not know where the multiplication sign is!!
Therefore I need to have an array where a string as such: 2+9-24+6
would be put into an array as:
|2|+|9|-|24|+|6|
    NOT
|2|+|9|-|2|4|+|6|

The method for returning the string after applying brackets works perfectly fine;
it checks the values in the array index on either side of the multiplication sign(*) and if they are both digits it returns the answer(the multiplication of both values) within parenthesis. If either one of them is a string it returns the constant and the string(for example; "2*X" will be returned as "(2X)" )

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong!!! I've been at this for days and my head is spinning! :'(

```
    int main()
    {
    int i=0,j=0,k=1,l=0;
    int count = 0;
    string calcString;
    char finalVector[1024];
    char array01[1024];
    char array02[1024];
    char newVector01[1024];
    char *newVector02[1024];

     cout<<"ENTER FORMULA TO CALCULATE"<<endl;
     cin>>calcString;
     strcpy(array01, calcString.c_str());

     while(array01[count]!=NULL)
     {
       array02[count]=array01[count];
       count++;
     }

     while(array02[k]!=NULL)
     {//HERE I AM SIMPLY TAKING THE SIGNS (*,/,+,-) INTO AN ARRAY
       if(array02[k]=='*')
       {
         newVector01[j] = array02[k];
         j++;
       }
       if(array02[k]=='/')
       {
         newVector01[j] = array02[k];
         j++;
       }
       if(array02[k]=='+')
       {
         newVector01[j] = array02[k];
         j++;
       }
       if(array02[k]=='-')
       {
         newVector01[j] = array02[k];
         j++;
       }
     k++;
    }
    cout<<"ARRAY OF SIGNS: "<<newVector01<<endl;

    //HERE I AM TOKENIZING THE ARRAY TO RETRIEVE THE INDIVIDUAL NUMBERS
    char *tokenizer = strtok(array02,"+-/*^()");

         while (tokenizer != NULL)
        {

           // printf ("%s ",tokenizer);
            newVector02[i] = tokenizer;
            tokenizer = strtok (NULL, "+-/*^()");
            i++;
        }
        cout<<endl;

        cout<<"ARRAY OF NUMBS: ";
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<newVector02[i]<<" ";
        }

        cout<<endl;

        //MY PROBLEM ARISES HERE!! WHEN I TRY TO PUT THEM ALL INTO A SINGLE ARRAY

        int a=0,b=0,c=0;
        while(newVector02[b]!=NULL)
        {
            finalVector[a]= newVector02[b];//PUTS THE NUMBERS INTO THEIR RIGHT PLACES
            finalVector[a+1]= newVector01[b];//PUTS THE SIGNS INTO THEIR RIGHT PLACES
            a=a+2;
            b++;
        }

        while(finalVector[c]!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<finalVector[c];
            c++;
        }


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Most likely by not using strtok.

Comment: if i don't use strtok, won't the number 24 be put into two different indexes of an array?

Comment: 2 and 4 are characters. They will always be in different indexes.

Comment: @aslg not if u tokenize them and then put them in an array... then they will be in one index.

Comment: Usually ppl use [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) for this sort of thing.

Comment: They will be in the same array, yet in different indexes. You didn't explain yourself clearly, you're not putting your string in an array, you're splitting it into many arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can never get "24" into a vector of chars `finalVector`. "24" is a string.

You can better use a vector of string.

```
For every string (str) in the vector, 
    if str.length() > 1
        This is a number. Convert it to int
    else
        This is an operator.
```

You can use this code to get the vector of string.

```
int main()
{
vector<string> finalVector;
string inputString;

cout << "Enter the string: ";
cin >> inputString;

int j;
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i = j + 1)
{
    string number = "";
    string sign;
    for (j = i; j < inputString.length(); j++)
    {
        if(isdigit(inputString.at(j)))
            number += inputString.at(j);
        else
        {
            sign = inputString.at(j);
            break;
        }
    }

    finalVector.push_back(number);
    finalVector.push_back(sign);
}

for (int i = 0; i < finalVector.size(); i++)
    cout << finalVector.at(i) << " ";

return 0;
/*test:
input: 2+34/3333*34
output: 2 + 34 / 3333 * 34
*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**this what i have done**

```
 int main()
{
    vector<string> expressionVector;
    char input[1024]="sin(2x+3y^7-3)";
    char* to_strtok = strdup(input);
    const char* delimiters = "^+-/()/t";
    char* token;
    char deli;
    for (token = strtok(to_strtok, delimiters);
         token != 0;
         token = strtok(0, delimiters))
    {
      deli = input[token - to_strtok + strlen(token)];
      if (deli != '\0')
      {

         ostringstream ss;
             ss << deli;

         expressionVector.push_back(token);
         expressionVector.push_back(ss.str());
      }
      else
      {

         expressionVector.push_back(token);
      }
}
    for (int i = 0; i < expressionVector.size(); i++)
            cout << expressionVector.at(i) << " ";

return 0;
}
```